# Umbraco hosted in Azure Container Apps using Docker login issue

Tags: azure, docker, umbraco

I'm hosting Umbraco version 12 in Azure Container Apps using a Docker image. I am having an intermittent issue where a user's login session to Umbraco back-office is lost and the user is redirected back to the login screen. When this happens each subsequent attempt to log back in is immediately redirected back to the login screen with no errors. Waiting an hour or so, or recreating the app from an image, temporarily fixes the issue. I say temporarily, the issue seems to occur randomly but it does eventually happen even after periods where the login session seems to persist normally.

There is nothing in the logs that suggests a reason for the issue, though each time it happens I can see that the container running the app is destroyed and restarted.

I've moved the images into an Azure Storage Container and I've also mounted both the umbraco/data and umbraco/logs folders in a shared volume via Azure Files. I have also tried running the container without these folders mounted and with variations of mounting the images in a similar volume, internally, and Azure Storage, but the same issue exists.

My immediate thought is the application state is being lost when the container is recreated, and that I should perhaps share this state somehow, though I haven't found any documentation that supports this nor how to share the state.

**EDIT**

Further investigation suggests that the issue is related to permissions when sharing folders using volume mounts under Azure Container Apps. Any advice on how to overcome these permission issues would be greatly appreciated

Here is the error from the logs which occurs when mounting the app/umbraco/Data folder (note, sharing the Logs folder appears to work fine as this log extract was written to the shared mount):

```
{"@t":"2023-10-22T10:11:51.5036377Z","@mt":"Error trying to release DB","@l":"Error","@x":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/app/umbraco/Data/TEMP/NuCache/NuCache.Media.db' is denied.\n ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n   at System.IO.RandomAccess.WriteAtOffset(SafeFileHandle handle, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, Int64 fileOffset)\n   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy.Write(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)\n   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.WriteSpan(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, ArraySegment`1 arraySegment)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.IO.TransactedCompoundFile.fput(Int64 position, Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.IO.TransactedCompoundFile.FileSection.Write(BlockRef block, FPut fput, Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.IO.TransactedCompoundFile.Write(UInt32 handle, Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.Storage.BTreeFileStoreV2.Update[T](IStorageHandle handleIn, ISerializer`1 serializer, T node)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.Collections.BPlusTree`2.StorageCache.OnItemRemoved(KeyValuePair`2 item)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.Collections.LurchTable`2.TryDequeue(Predicate`1 predicate, KeyValuePair`2& value)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.Collections.LurchTable`2.TryDequeue(KeyValuePair`2& value)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.Collections.BPlusTree`2.StorageCache.Flush()\n   at CSharpTest.Net.Collections.BPlusTree`2.StorageCache.Commit()\n   at CSharpTest.Net.Collections.BPlusTree`2.CommitChanges(Boolean requiresLock)\n   at CSharpTest.Net.Collections.BPlusTree`2.Dispose()\n   at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.PublishedCache.ContentStore.ReleaseLocalDb()","SourceContext":"ContentStore","ProcessId":1,"ProcessName":"dotnet","ThreadId":25,"ApplicationId":"d2b6c12ab2d22552b3a7faee0509e6139f633afc","MachineName":"peach-cms--lt6pksz-dd5b6f5cc-kltdw","Log4NetLevel":"ERROR"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to look at Carl Sargunar's blog posts and YouTube videos about Umbraco on Docker?

Carl has been working a lot with Umbraco on Docker over the past few years, he previously talked about the same topic at various platforms, like Codegarden 2022, and these blog posts and videos can help you.

- Blog post 1: https://archive.24days.in/umbraco-cms/2021/micro-architectures-part1/
- Blog post 2: https://archive.24days.in/umbraco-cms/2021/micro-architectures-part2/
- YouTube video 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdZHdtDPIlg
- YouTube video 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8g_73YmYlY

Comment: I haven't. I'll check it out thanks. To be honest I don't think it's an issue with Docker specifically, it's working fine running in a Docker environment, and it works in Kubernetes, I suspect it is something unique to Azure Container Apps as I've had issues similar to this before and haven't found the answer

Comment: You're welcome. When you find the issue, please remember to post your answer here. Good luck!